# Call a function if request time has exceeded 500ms

Tags: jquery, ajax

Is there a way to call a function, for example, one that inserts a loading GIF, if an ajax request has taken more than a specified length of time? It also shouldn't be called if the request finishes before that time is up.

I'm thinking maybe using a `setTimeout` for 500ms and then destroying it in the success callback, meaning it may not run if it's destroyed before 500ms is over.

EDIT: I don't want the request to fail after this 500ms. It should keep continuing to run.

Comment: Your idea seems correct. It's what I'd do.

Comment: Yeah I guess I'll go with that, then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Keep ajax request and call a function after 500ms

To execute the function after 500ms and keep the request alive use [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)

```
$.ajax({
    url: "hodor.html",
    error: function () {
        clearTimeout(timeoutID);

    },
    success: function () {
        clearTimeout(timeoutID);

    }
});

var timeoutID = setTimeout(function () {
    console.log("The timeout passed");
}, 500);
```

### Abort ajax request and call a function after 500ms

Use ajax built in [timeout](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) handling. Set `timeout` in ms and `error` callback function. Identify timeouts in the callback with `t`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "hodor.html",
    timeout: 500,
    error: function(x, t, m) {
        if (t === "timeout") {
            // Timeout
        } else {

        }
    },
    success: function(){

    }
});
```

Comment: I don't want it to fail though.

Comment: @avoliva ok in this case your solution is sufficient. I edited my answer but i kept the old too so that maybe it will be helpful to someone in the future.

Comment: to be fair, i was just using 500ms as an example.

Answer (score -1):

There is a property called timeout provided by jQuery ajax definition. In case of timeout it will go to your error callback and after that it will go to your complete/done. You can look at it.

As per jQuery Spec

> Set a timeout (in milliseconds) for the request. This will override any global timeout set with $.ajaxSetup(). The timeout period starts at the point the $.ajax call is made; if several other requests are in progress and the browser has no connections available, it is possible for a request to time out before it can be sent. In jQuery 1.4.x and below, the XMLHttpRequest object will be in an invalid state if the request times out; accessing any object members may throw an exception. In Firefox 3.0+ only, script and JSONP requests cannot be cancelled by a timeout; the script will run even if it arrives after the timeout period.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Hope this helps.

Happy Learning :)

Comment: If you do this, make sure you can tell the difference between a timed out request and an error response.

Comment: Timeout ends the request right with an error, right? I want the request to continue even after this 500ms is over.

Comment: Then dont specify the timeout. It will continue by default provided no exception is thrown and returned from your server code. Otherwise, it will return with an error

Comment: It's rather confusing. In the answer, you say use timeout, then in a comment you say don't use a timeout. Which is it? using a timeout will prevent the success callback from running, which seems to be NOT what the OP is asking for.

Comment: Timeout ends the request right with an error, right? I want the request to continue even after this 500ms is over.  - These were the comments by OP. For which I said "Then dont specify the timeout. It will continue by default provided no exception is thrown and returned from your server code. Otherwise, it will return with an error"

Comment: which means... the answer isn't useful. it's wrong. it doesn't do what the op wants.